# Delete user from analytics data in BigQuery

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery

I'm trying to delete a user from the set of dated tables in the Firebase Analytics data dumped to BigQuery, but apparently wildcards cannot be used in `DELETE` queries.

Is there another way to delete a user from all my database tables?

Comment: It sounds like you need to run a DELETE statement over each table.

Comment: Then it's hard to comply with the GDPR since I should be able to delete users' information when they request it.

Comment: You can run the DELETE statements in a loop using a client library or Bash with the `bq` CLI.